# Is ChatGPT wrong about the definition of unrecognizable and undecidable languages?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, computability, undecidability, computation-models

I asked ChatGPT to give me the difference between unrecognizable and undecidable languages, and this what it gave me:

- Unrecognizable languages can be accepted by a Turing machine, but the machine may not always halt on inputs outside the language.
- Undecidable languages cannot be decided by a Turing machine for all possible inputs; there is no algorithm that can determine membership for every input in these languages.

I am new to this topic, so I could be wrong, but I think that both of these are incorrect. I think the definition for unrecognizable languages it gave me is actually the definition for recognizable languages, because the a recognizer accepts strings in the language while it rejects or loops on everything else.
And I think its definition for undecidable languages is approximately actually for unrecognizable languages.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 7):

ChatGPT is not capable of being “right” or “wrong” about anything. It is however capable of producing very plausible sounding nonsense about just any subject. Never trust anything it says.

Comment: If ChatGPT produces a coherent statement, then that claim can be evaluated for accuracy. However, that's a big "if". Language is a social contract where Alice intends to be understandable and Bob intends to understand. At the time of writing, large language models have no intention.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I just wanted to confirm that it is indeed false in this regard.